# How to prevent visual studio debugger from stepping into arguments evaluation?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I'm using VS 2010 to code native C++.

Sometimes when debugging, I have stuff like :

```
myFunction(arg1->getValue(),arg2->getValue(),arg3->getValue());
```

When steping in, the debugger goes through all the getValues() (it's a schematic example) before entering myFunction code. If I step over, it never enters myFunction code. Is there a way to make it go directly into myFunction code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click, select the menu item **Step Into Specific**/myfunction

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is Shitf+Alt+F11 on my configuration

Comment: Nice, I never saw that. But Shif+Alt+F11 doesn't work for me, I guess you have to define a new keyboard shortcut.